# div with angle is not working properly in FF 16

Tags: html, css

I tested this [example](http://codepen.io/JosephSilber/pen/bFfqn) of div with 45 degree angle.

This is the final result that I would like to get:

[image]

This is the result that I get in my browser:

[image]

In IE I get only the test without the green background. How I can fix the problem?
I use FF 16.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a fix for you (note it doesn't include IE fix for gradient background):

```
h1:after {
    content: '';
    background: linear-gradient(top left, #5FA309, #3B8018);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#5FA309), to(#3B8018));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top left,  #5FA309,  #3B8018);
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px; right: -11px;
    width: 21px;
    height: 21px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: you may try to use `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5FA309', endColorstr='#3B8018');` to get it working in IE, but Im not sure

Comment: post an OS + browser version pls so it can be fixed, I will edit a post to fit IE specifics